# How to scramble data in SQL?

Tags: t-sql

We have some data in the SQL server table that needs to scramble. Some data are string and some data are date.

What is best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by scramble? Hash, encrypt, something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about [Obfuscating your SQL Server Data](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/obfuscating-your-sql-server-data/)? (To create a development version based on the production data without exposing the production data itself)

Or do you want it [encrypted](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/encryption_2005_1_p1.aspx)?

Comment: That is what I am looking for Obfuscating. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 introduced encryption support. Check out this article [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/encryption_2005_2_p1.aspx).